# ImportTabSepData example

Tags: mdriven

could you please share model with [ThingImporter viewmodel](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Convergence_%E2%80%93_ViewModels,_import,_export,_multi_search,_synchronization_and_Excel)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample was lost - but I made a new one that download from here https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/File:ImportTabSepExample.modlr
Also updated the page with a link at the bottom.

Also: Turnkey experienced a bug for ImportTabSeperated - that is fixed today.